# Understanding the Send trait

Tags: rust

I am trying to wrap my head around `Send + Sync` traits. I get the intuition behind `Sync` - this is the traditional thread safety(like in `C++`). The object does the necessary locking(interior mutability if needed), so threads can safely access it.

But the `Send` part is bit unclear. I understand why things like `Rc` are `Send` only - the object can be given to a different thread, but non-atomic operations make it thread unsafe.

1. What is the intuition behind `Send`? Does it mean the object can be copied/moved into another thread context, and continues to be valid after the copy/move?
2. Any examples scenarios for "`Sync` but no `Send`" would really help. Please also point to any rust libraries for this case (I found several for the opposite though)

For (2), I found some threads which use structs with pointers to data on stack/thread local storage as examples. But these are unsafe anyways(Sync or otherwise).

Comment: `Sync` but not `Send` does not make sense. If an object can be synchronized between threads, it can also be sent from one thread to another, by definition.

Comment: Not exactly: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/sync-but-not-send/21551

Answer (score 113):

[`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) allows an object to to be used by two threads A and B at the *same* time. This is trivial for non-mutable objects, but mutations need to be synchronized (performed in sequence with the same order being seen by all threads). This is often done using a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) which allows one thread to proceed while others must wait. By enforcing a shared order of changes, these types can turn a non-`Sync` object into a `Sync` object. Another mechanism for making objects `Sync` is to use atomic types, which are essentially `Sync` primitives.

[`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) allows an object to be used by two threads A and B at *different* times. Thread A can create and use an object, then send it to thread B, so thread B can use the object while thread A cannot. The Rust ownership model can be used to enforce this non-overlapping use. Hence the ownership model is an important part of Rust's `Send` thread safety, and may be the reason that `Send` is less intuitive than `Sync` when comparing with other languages.

Using the above definitions, it should be apparent why there are few examples of types that are `Sync` but not `Send`. If an object can be used safely by two threads at the same time (`Sync`) then it can be used safely by two threads at different times (`Send`). Hence, `Sync` usually implies `Send`. Any exception probably relates to `Send`'s transfer of ownership between threads, which affects which thread runs the `Drop` handler and deallocates the value.

Most objects can be used safely by different threads if the uses can be guaranteed to be at different times. Hence, most types are `Send`.

[`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) is an exception. It does not implement `Send`. `Rc` allows data to have multiple owners. If one owner in thread A could send the `Rc` to another thread, giving ownership to thread B, there could be other owners in thread A that can still use the object. Since the reference count is modified non-atomically, the value of the count on the two threads may get out of sync and one thread may drop the pointed-at value while there are owners in the other thread.

[`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) is an `Rc` that uses an atomic type for the reference count. Hence it can be used by multiple threads without the count getting out of sync.  If the data that the `Arc` points to is `Sync`, the entire object is `Sync`.  If the data is not `Sync` (e.g. a mutable type), it can be made `Sync` using a `Mutex`. Hence the proliferation of `Arc<Mutex<T>>` types in multithreaded Rust code.

Comment: Great Answer. Just a small point;  "If the data is not `Sync` (e.g. a mutable type), it can be made `Sync` ..."   -- A mutable type can be a mutable reference which is `Sync`.  eg. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06f9be034bc557416db904b71aa1d9b7

Comment: @vikram2784 Be aware that `rayon::scope::spawn` has different parameter type with `std::thread::spawn`. Also note that `&mut T` is Sync if and only if `&&mut T` is Send, so it's eventually immutable in other threads. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html

Answer (score 21):

`Send` means that a type is safe to *move* from one thread to another. If the same type also implements `Copy`, this also means that it is safe to *copy*  from one thread to another.

`Sync` means that a type is safe to reference from multiple threads at the same time. Specifically, that `&T` is `Send` and can be moved/copied to another thread if `T` is `Sync`.

So `Send` and `Sync` capture two different aspects of thread safety:

- Non-`Send` types can only ever be owned by a single thread, since they cannot be moved or copied to other threads.
- Non-`Sync` types can only be used by a single thread *at any single time*, since their references cannot be moved or copied to other threads. They can still be moved between threads if they implement `Send`.

It rarely makes sense to have `Sync` without `Send`, as being able to use a type from different threads would usually mean that moving ownership between threads should also be possible. Although they are technically different, so it is conceivable that certain types can be `Sync` but not `Send`.

Most types that own data will be `Send`, as there are few cases where data can't be moved from one thread to another (and not be accessed from the original thread afterwards).
Some common exceptions:

- Raw pointers are never `Send` nor `Sync`.
- Types that share ownership of data without thread synchronization (for instance `Rc`).
- Types that borrow data that is not `Sync`.
- Types from external libraries or the operating system that are not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks all. Subtle, but IIUC: If whole of Struct Foo { } can be moved, it is Send. If &struct Foo can be shared, it is Sync. One contrived example of Sync but no Send: (assuming scoped threads for lifetime issues) - Struct Foo{} uses thread local storage to keep some state, and exposes thread safe get/set methods for that state.  Now the &Foo can be passed around, but not Foo itself.  Does this sound right?

Comment: [This](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/sync-but-not-send/21551?u=optimisticpeach) URLO thread talks about it; mentioning both thread-local storage and weird ffi types. So yes, your `&Foo` can be passed around but not the `Foo` itself.
 [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=089dfb9059dcf88728511d82cd05b608) is a curious example; you can't pass around a `&Mutex<Foo>` since [`Mutex<T>: Sync where T: Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Sync).

Comment: Also a bit surprising that Box<T> is both Sync/Send, as one would expect it to to be Send only, guaranteeing unique ownership. My reasoning being: it is like std::unique_ptr in C++, which is move only. Along the same lines, raw pointers could be Send only, as long as a single thread owns/uses the pointer. But I guess raw pointers fall in the unsafe/grey area

Comment: `Box<T>` can be treated as essentially a `T`. It represents ownership of a `T`, and will also implement the `Send`/`Sync` traits if `T: Send`/`T: Sync`. The only thing that a `Box<T>` semantically does is move the object into the heap and give you a pointer to it. This pointer is special though, since the pointer (I'll call it box) now owns the object. You should treat a `Box<T>` the same as a `T` in most cases.

Answer (score 13):

#### Overall

`Send` and `Sync` exist to help thinking about the types when many threads are involved. In a single thread world, there is no need for `Send` and `Sync` to exist.

It may help also to not always think about `Send` and `Sync` as *allowing* you to do something, or *giving you power* to do something. On the contrary, think about `!Send` and `!Sync` as ways of *forbidding* or *preventing* you of doing multi-thread problematic stuff.

#### For the definition of `Send` and `Sync`

If some type `X` is `Send`, then if you have an owned `X`, you can move it into another thread.

- This can be problematic if `X` is somehow related to multi/shared-ownership.
- `Rc` has a problem with this, since having one `Rc` allows you to create more owned `Rc`'s (by cloning it), but you don't want any of those to pass into other threads. The problem is that many threads could be making more clones of that `Rc` at the same time, and the counter of the owners inside of it doesn't work well in that multi-thread situation - because even if each thread would own an `Rc`, there would be only one counter really, and access into it would not be synchronized.
- `Arc` may work better. At least it's owner's counter is capable of dealing with the situation mentioned above. So in that regard, `Arc` is ok to allow `Send`'ing. But only if the inner type is both `Send` and `Sync`. For example, an `Arc<Rc>` is still problematic - remembering that `Rc` forbids `Send` (`!Send`) - because multiple threads having their own owned clone of that `Arc<Rc>` could still invoke the `Rc`'s own "multi-thread" problems - the `Arc` itself can't protect the threads from doing that. The other requirement of `Arc<T>`, to being `Send`, also requiring `T` to be `Sync` is not a big of a deal, because if a type is already forbidding `Send`'ing, it will likely also be forbidding `Sync`'ing.
- So if some type forbids `Send`ing, then doesn't matter what other types you try wrapping around it, you won't be able to make it "sendable" into another thread.

If some type `X` is `Sync`, then if multiple threads happened to somehow have an `&X` each, they all can safely use that `&X`.

- This is problematic if `&X` allows interior mutability, and you'd want to forbid `Sync` if you want to prevent multiple threads having `&X`.
- So if `X` has a problem with `Send`ing, it will basically also have a problem with `Sync`ing.
- It's also problematic for `Cell` - which doesn't actually forbids `Send`ing. Since `Cell` allows interior mutation by only having an `&Cell`, and that mutation access doesn't guarantee anything in a multithread situation, it must forbid `Sync`ing - that is, the situation of multiple threads having `&Cell` must not be allowed (in general). Regarding it being `Send`, an owned `Cell` can still be moved into another thread, as long as there won't be `&Cell`'s anywhere else.
- `Mutex` may work better. It also allows interior mutation, and in which case it knows how to deal when many threads are trying to do it - the `Mutex` will only require that nothing inside of it forbids `Send`'ing - otherwise, it's the same problem that `Arc` would have to deal with. All being good, the `Mutex` is both `Send` and `Sync`.
- This is not a practical example, but a curious note: if we have a `Mutex<Cell>` (which is redundant, but oh well), where `Cell` itself forbids `Sync`, the `Mutex` is able to deal with that problem, and still be (or "re-allow") `Sync`. This is because, once a thread got access into that `Cell`, we known it won't have to deal with other threads still trying to access others `&Cell` at the same time, since the `Mutex` will be locked and preventing this from happening.

#### Mutate a value in multi-thread

In theory you could share a `Mutex` between threads!
If you try to simply move an owned `Mutex`, you will get it done, but this is of no use, since you'd want multiple threads having some access to it at the same time.
Since it's `Sync`, you're allowed to share a `&Mutex` between threads, and it's lock method indeed only requires a `&Mutex`.
But trying this is problematic, let's say: you're in the `main` thread, then you create a `Mutex` and then a reference to it, a `&Mutex`, and then create another thread `Z` which you try to pass the `&Mutex` into.
The problem is that the `Mutex` has only one owner, and that is inside the `main` thread. If for some reason the thread `Z` outlives the `main` thread, that `&Mutex` would be dangling. So even if the `Sync` in the `Mutex` doesn't particularly forbids you of sending/sharing `&Mutex` between threads, you'll likely not get it done in this way, for lifetime reasons. `Arc` to the rescue!
`Arc` will get rid of that lifetime problem. instead of it being owned by a particular scope in a particular thread, it can be multi-owned, by multi-threads.
So using an `Arc<Mutex>` will allow a value to be co-owned and shared, and offer interior mutability between many threads. In sum, the `Mutex` itself re-allows `Sync`ing while not particularly forbidding `Send`ing, and the `Arc` doesn't particularly forbids neither while offering shared ownership (avoiding lifetime problems).

#### Small list of types

Types that are `Send` and `Sync`, are those that don't particularly forbids neither:

- primitives, *`Arc`*, *`Mutex`* - depending on the inner types

Types that are `Send` and `!Sync`, are those that offer (multithread unsync) interior mutability:

- *`Cell`*, *`RefCell`* - depending on the inner type

Types that are `!Send` and `!Sync`, are those that offer (multithread unsync) co-ownership:

- *`Rc`*

I don't know types that are `!Send` and `Sync`;

Comment: Types that are `!Send` and `Sync` are for example: `RwLockRead(Write)Guard` and `MutexGuard` from `std::sync`

Answer (score 1):

According to
[Rustonomicon: Send and Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html)

> A type is Send if it is safe to send it to another thread.

> A type is Sync if it is safe to share between threads (**T is Sync if and only if &T is Send**).

Comment: This part of learning Rust has me confused. Shouldn't it be `T& is Sync if and only if T is Send`? My understanding is that `T` transfers ownership so multiple threads couldn't possibly read concurrently (Sync). Or is my mistake that I'm thinking of typical structs instead of smart pointers?