# How to start and stop a worker thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a following requirement which is standard in other programming languages but I don't know how to do in Rust.

I have a class, I want to write a method to spawn a worker thread that satisfied 2 conditions:

- After spawning the worker thread, the function is return (so other place does not need to wait)
- There is a mechanism for stopping this thread.

For example, here is my dummy code:

```
struct A {
    thread: JoinHandle<?>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<()>{
        self.thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut i = 0;
            loop {
                self.call();
                i = 1 + i;
                if i > 5 {
                    return
                }
            }
        });
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) -> std::thread::Result<_> {
        self.thread.join()
    }

    pub fn call(&mut self) {
        println!("hello world");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A{};
    a.run();
}
```

I have an error at `thread: JoinHandle<?>`. What is the type of thread in this case. And is my code correct to start and stop a worker thread?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the `fn call` does in the actual code? Because you'd need to use a `Mutex`, which means that if you call `stop()` your worker thread could deadlock.

Comment: In `fn call`, I will access some attributes of struct `A`, that why I need to use `move` here. Is this enough? Because the logic is complex, can you help me to elaborate what else I need to mention here?

Comment: Struct A has some attributes related to `mpsc` package and also some attributes with type `Arc<Mutex`. I don't know if these will affect the way to get the thing done?

Comment: Almost, just a slight clarification. Does `A` need to be shared, or would it be enough to share a `struct AData`? Further, do you actually need access to the _attributes_ before the worker thread is done? If not, then would `fn stop(...) -> AData` (simplified) be sufficient?

Comment: `Does A need to be shared`: if you mean sharing for the worker thread, then no, the worker thread only needs A's attributes. For sharing the whole object to other places, then yes, some other places will hold the reference to A object. (I think this is obviously of this point, or I might miss something).

For your second point, it is interesting. I start to understand the problem you mentioned. Right now, it's not. But out of curiosity, how do you solve in case of we need access to the attributes before the worker thread is done?

Comment: I think I understand the underlying problem. I'll write a few examples as an answer. If they aren't sufficient, I'll clarify issues afterwards :)

Comment: "which is standard in other programming languages" "There is a mechanism for stopping this thread." few languages can stop random threads at arbitrary points, and AFAIK the most famous language with this ability (Java) [has deprecated all interruption methods as inherently dangerous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). The proper way to stop a thread would be for the thread and caller to share a signalling channel (e.g. an AtomicBool, a oneshot channel, …), and for the thread to regularly check if it's been told to stop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, the `T` in [`join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) on a [`JoinHandle<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html) returns the result of the closure passed to [`thread::spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html). *So in your case `JoinHandle<?>` would need to be `JoinHandle<()>` as your closure returns *nothing*, i.e. [`()` (unit)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html).*

Other than that, your dummy code contains a few additional issues.

- The return type of `run()` is incorrect, and would need to at least be `Result<(), ()>`.
- The `thread` field would need to be `Option<JoinHandle<()>` to be able to *handle* `fn stop(&mut self)` as [`join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) consumes the `JoinHandle`.
- However, you're attempting to pass `&mut self` to the closure, which brings a lot more issues, boiling down to multiple mutable references

  - This could be solved with e.g. `Mutex<A>`. However, if you call `stop()` then that could lead to a deadlock instead.

---

However, since it was dummy code, and you clarified in the comments. Let me try and clarify what you meant with a few examples. *This includes me rewriting your dummy code.*

### Result after worker is done

If you don't need access to the data while the worker thread is running, then you can make a new `struct WorkerData`. Then in `run()` you copy/clone the data you need from `A` (or as I've renamed it `Worker`). Then in the closure you finally return `data` again, so you can acquire it through `join()`.

```rust
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

struct WorkerData {
    ...
}

impl WorkerData {
    pub fn call(&mut self) {
        println!("hello world");
    }
}

struct Worker {
    thread: Option<JoinHandle<WorkerData>>,
}

impl Worker {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { thread: None }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        // Create `WorkerData` and copy/clone whatever is needed from `self`
        let mut data = WorkerData {};

        self.thread = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut i = 0;
            loop {
                data.call();
                i = 1 + i;
                if i > 5 {
                    // Return `data` so we get in through `join()`
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) -> Option<thread::Result<WorkerData>> {
        if let Some(handle) = self.thread.take() {
            Some(handle.join())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

You don't really need `thread` to be `Option<JoinHandle<WorkerData>>` and instead could just use `JoinHandle<WorkerData>>`. Because if you wanted to call `run()` again, it would just be easier to reassign the variable holding the `Worker`.

So now we can simplify `Worker`, removing the `Option` and change `stop` to consume `thread` instead, along with creating `new() -> Self` in place of `run(&mut self)`.

```rust
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

struct Worker {
    thread: JoinHandle<WorkerData>,
}

impl Worker {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // Create `WorkerData` and copy/clone whatever is needed from `self`
        let mut data = WorkerData {};

        let thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut i = 0;
            loop {
                data.call();
                i = 1 + i;
                if i > 5 {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });

        Self { thread }
    }

    pub fn stop(self) -> thread::Result<WorkerData> {
        self.thread.join()
    }
}
```

### Shared `WorkerData`

If you want to retain references to `WorkerData` between multiple threads, then you'd need to use [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html). Since you additionally want to be able to mutate it, you'll need to use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

If you'll only be mutating within a single thread, then you could alternatively you a [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html), which compared to a `Mutex` will allow you to lock and obtain multiple immutable references at the same time.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

struct Worker {
    thread: JoinHandle<()>,
    data: Arc<RwLock<WorkerData>>,
}

impl Worker {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // Create `WorkerData` and copy/clone whatever is needed from `self`
        let data = Arc::new(RwLock::new(WorkerData {}));

        let thread = thread::spawn({
            let data = data.clone();
            move || {
                let mut i = 0;
                loop {
                    if let Ok(mut data) = data.write() {
                        data.call();
                    }

                    i = 1 + i;
                    if i > 5 {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Self { thread, data }
    }

    pub fn stop(self) -> thread::Result<Arc<RwLock<WorkerData>>> {
        self.thread.join()?;
        // You might be able to unwrap and get the inner `WorkerData` here
        Ok(self.data)
    }
}
```

If you add a method to be able to obtain `data` in the form of `Arc<RwLock<WorkerData>>`. Then if you clone the `Arc` and lock it (the inner `RwLock`) prior to calling `stop()`, then that would result in a deadlock.
To avoid that, any `data()` method should return `&WorkerData` or `&mut WorkerData` instead of the `Arc`. That way you'd be unable to call `stop()` and cause a deadlock.

### Flag to stop worker

If you actually want to stop the worker thread, then you'd have to use a flag to signal it to do so. You can create a flag in the form of a shared [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html).

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

struct Worker {
    thread: JoinHandle<()>,
    data: Arc<RwLock<WorkerData>>,
    stop_flag: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl Worker {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // Create `WorkerData` and copy/clone whatever is needed from `self`
        let data = Arc::new(RwLock::new(WorkerData {}));

        let stop_flag = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

        let thread = thread::spawn({
            let data = data.clone();
            let stop_flag = stop_flag.clone();
            move || {
                // let mut i = 0;
                loop {
                    if stop_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if let Ok(mut data) = data.write() {
                        data.call();
                    }

                    // i = 1 + i;
                    // if i > 5 {
                    //     return;
                    // }
                }
            }
        });

        Self {
            thread,
            data,
            stop_flag,
        }
    }

    pub fn stop(self) -> thread::Result<Arc<RwLock<WorkerData>>> {
        self.stop_flag.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.thread.join()?;
        // You might be able to unwrap and get the inner `WorkerData` here
        Ok(self.data)
    }
}
```

### Multiple threads and multiple tasks

If you want multiple kinds of tasks processed, spread across multiple threads, then here's a more generalized example.

You already mentioned using [`mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html). So you can use a [`Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html) and [`Receiver`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) along with a custom `Task` and `TaskResult` enum.

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

pub enum Task {
    ...
}

pub enum TaskResult {
    ...
}

pub type TaskSender = Sender<Task>;
pub type TaskReceiver = Receiver<Task>;

pub type ResultSender = Sender<TaskResult>;
pub type ResultReceiver = Receiver<TaskResult>;

struct Worker {
    threads: Vec<JoinHandle<()>>,
    task_sender: TaskSender,
    result_receiver: ResultReceiver,
    stop_flag: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl Worker {
    pub fn new(num_threads: usize) -> Self {
        let (task_sender, task_receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        let (result_sender, result_receiver) = mpsc::channel();

        let task_receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(task_receiver));

        let stop_flag = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

        Self {
            threads: (0..num_threads)
                .map(|_| {
                    let task_receiver = task_receiver.clone();
                    let result_sender = result_sender.clone();
                    let stop_flag = stop_flag.clone();

                    thread::spawn(move || loop {
                        if stop_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                            break;
                        }

                        let task_receiver = task_receiver.lock().unwrap();

                        if let Ok(task) = task_receiver.recv() {
                            drop(task_receiver);

                            // Perform the `task` here

                            // If the `Task` results in a `TaskResult` then create it and send it back
                            let result: TaskResult = ...;
                            // The `SendError` can be ignored as it only occurs if the receiver
                            // has already been deallocated
                            let _ = result_sender.send(result);
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    })
                })
                .collect(),
            task_sender,
            result_receiver,
            stop_flag,
        }
    }

    pub fn stop(self) -> Vec<thread::Result<()>> {
        drop(self.task_sender);

        self.stop_flag.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);

        self.threads
            .into_iter()
            .map(|t| t.join())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn request(&mut self, task: Task) {
        self.task_sender.send(task).unwrap();
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn result_receiver(&mut self) -> &ResultReceiver {
        &self.result_receiver
    }
}
```

An example of using the `Worker` along with sending tasks and receiving task results, would then look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut worker = Worker::new(4);

    // Request that a `Task` is performed
    worker.request(task);

    // Receive a `TaskResult` if any are pending
    if let Ok(result) = worker.result_receiver().try_recv() {
        // Process the `TaskResult`
    }
}
```

In a few cases you might need to implement `Send` for `Task` and/or `TaskResult`. *Check out ["Understanding the Send trait"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428096/understanding-the-send-trait).*

```rust
unsafe impl Send for Task {}
unsafe impl Send for TaskResult {}
```

Comment: This took quite a bit of time, but I hope some of these examples will provide you and others help :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I wish I can upvote x1000 times now. I am reading and it really helps me a lot.

Comment: Whenever you're done digesting the answer feel free to comment if there's any issues, or alternatively accept the answer if it resolved your issue/question :)

Comment: Hi. My apologies for late reply. Your answer helps me a lot. I have an another question, based on this problem, but more well-defined, can you help me to answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654251/rust-calling-an-unsafe-library-object-of-from-a-different-thread

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter of a `JoinHandle` should be the return type of the thread's function.

In this case, the return type is an empty tuple `()`, pronounced [unit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html). It is used when there is only one value possible, and is the implicit "return type" of functions when no return type is specified.

You can just write `JoinHandle<()>` to represent that the function will not return anything.

(Note: Your code will run into some borrow checker issues with `self.call()`, which will probably need to be solved with `Arc<Mutex<Self>>`, but that's another question.)

Comment: The `Result<()>` in `run()` is also incorrect, along with `thread` needing to be `Option<JoinHandle<()>>` to be able to handle `stop` :)

Comment: That what I think what will happen next because `self` has taken away from the worker thread. Can you help me to bring some light for this, too?