# Calling an unsafe library object of from a different thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, unsafe

I am using [tikv/raft-rs](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs) library for implementing a consensus system. This library has a [RawNode](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs/blob/master/src/raw_node.rs#L254) object which is a thread-unsafe object. We must execute some functions on this object periodically ([example](https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs/blob/master/examples/five_mem_node/main.rs#L64)), hence I use a new thread for executing.

Here are the constraints:

- I need to have this object on the main-thread doesn't have this object for accessing some its internal states. (e.g.: `raw_node.is_leader`)
- This object must be accessed on a worker thread.

Because of these constraints, this seems impossible because:

- If I create this object, and move to the new thread, the main thread cannot call its state.
- If I keep this object on the main thread object, I cannot use `Arc<Mutex<>>` because this object doesn't implement `Copy` method.

Here is my code:

```
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, mpsc};
use std::collections::{VecDeque, HashMap};
use raft::RawNode;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender, TryRecvError};

use protobuf::Message as PbMessage;
use raft::eraftpb::ConfState;
use raft::storage::MemStorage;
use raft::{prelude::*, StateRole};
use regex::Regex;
use crate::proposal::Proposal;
use crate::{proposal, batch};
use std::{str, thread};
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};
use crate::batch::Mailbox;

pub struct Node {
    core: Arc<Mutex<CoreNode>>
}

#[derive(Copy)]
struct CoreNode {
    raft_group: RawNode<MemStorage>,
}


impl Node {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let cfg = Config {
            election_tick: 10,
            heartbeat_tick: 3,
            ..Default::default()
        };
        let storage = MemStorage::new();

        let core = Arc::new(Mutex::new(CoreNode {
            raft_group: RawNode::new(&cfg, storage).unwrap()
        }));

        thread::spawn(move || {
            core.lock().unwrap().run();
            return;
        });

        Node { core: core.clone() }
    }

    pub fn is_leader(&self) -> bool {
        return self.core.lock().unwrap().raft_group.raft.state == StateRole::Leader;

    }
}

impl CoreNode {
    pub fn run(mut self) {}
}
```

When compiling, here is the error:

```
22 | #[derive(Copy)]
   |          ^^^^
23 | struct CoreNode {
24 |     raft_group: RawNode<MemStorage>,
   |     ------------------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
   |
```

My question is: How can I design around this problem.

Comment: Some code would be nice, yes. I'm slightly unsure what you mean by the "must be on the main thread", and why you can't use `Arc`. Since whenever the workers are done, you could [`try_unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap) on the main thread

Comment: @vallentin I have updated my question with code.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that `run()` needs to consume `CoreNode`? In short, why `mut self` and not `&mut self`?

Comment: Yes. The `run` method needs to modify the variable inside of `raft_group` object.  However, I think the problem because of the `raft_group`'s datatype, which is `RawNode` right? so if we use `RawNode` instead of CoreNode, the problem is still same.

Comment: Unsure if that clarified `run` for me. For instance if you're able to change `run` to `run(&mut self)`, then you can remove `derive(Copy)`, clone `core` and then the code you've provided would compile