# How to specify a Rust struct field must satisfy a trait when the struct has async methods?

Tags: rust, async-await

Creating an authentication server.

I want a `PGUserRepo` struct, which implements a `UserRepo` trait `async fn create`.

The `PGUserRepo` should have a field that implements the `Hasher` trait.

However when I try to restrict the `PGUserRepo` field to be a `dyn Hasher` I get the error

"the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn domain::hasher::Hasher + 'static)".

If I make the `PGUserRepo` field the concrete implementing type, `ArgonHasher`, no error. But I don't want the `PGUserRepo` to care about what kind of `Hasher` was given to it, just that it implements the `Hasher` trait.

I have tried wrapping the `hasher` field in various combinations of Box, Arc, and Mutex, but I do not understand the root of why calling it an `ArgonHasher` is fine but saying it is some implementer of `Hasher` is not.

Code, collapsed to one file for convenience:

```rust
pub trait Hasher {
    fn hash(&self, password: String) -> Result<String, HasherError>;
}

pub struct ArgonHasher {}

impl Hasher for ArgonHasher {
    fn hash(&self, password: String) -> Result<String, HasherError> {
        let result = argon2id13::pwhash(
            &password.as_bytes(),
            argon2id13::OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
            argon2id13::MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        );
        match result {
            Ok(hashed_password_result) => match std::str::from_utf8(&hashed_password_result.0) {
                Ok(hashed_password_utf8) => Ok(String::from(hashed_password_utf8)),
                Err(e) => Err(HasherError::from(e)),
            },
            Err(e) => Err(HasherError::from(e)),
        }
    }
}

impl From<()> for HasherError {
    fn from(_: ()) -> Self {
        HasherError::HasherError {
            message: String::from(""),
        }
    }
}

impl From<std::str::Utf8Error> for HasherError {
    fn from(cause: std::str::Utf8Error) -> Self {
        HasherError::HasherError {
            message: format!("{}", cause),
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait UserRepo {
    async fn create(&self, user: User) -> Result<User, UserRepoError>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum UserRepoError {
    UserAlreadyExistsError { field: String, value: String },
    UserRepoError { message: String },
}

impl fmt::Display for UserRepoError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *&self {
            UserRepoError::UserAlreadyExistsError { field, value } => {
                f.write_str(&format!("User with {}={} already exists", field, value))
            }
            UserRepoError::UserRepoError { message } => f.write_str(&message),
        }
    }
}


pub struct PGUserRepo {
    conn_pool: PgPool,
    hasher: &'static dyn Hasher,
}

impl PGUserRepo {
    pub fn new(conn_pool: PgPool, hasher: &'static dyn Hasher) -> Self {
        PGUserRepo { conn_pool, hasher }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl UserRepo for PGUserRepo {
    async fn create(&self, user: User) -> Result<User, UserRepoError> {
    # Compiler error is on this function
    # hasher is not even used in this function yet, it's just a field on PGuserRepo
}
```

Bonus: I don't really need the `Hasher` trait `hash` to have a reference to `self` but without it I get "error[E0038]: the trait `domain::hasher::Hasher` cannot be made into an object".

Comment: See also [Sharing a struct with trait objects as properties across threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255263/sharing-a-struct-with-trait-objects-as-properties-across-threads) That Q&A is for boxed traits but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker trait [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) is used to indicate when a type is safe to be transferred between threads. It is implemented by default when the compiler deems it to be safe. However, you have a trait object `hasher` that has no constraint on if it can be shared between threads safely.

This comes up here because `async` code is usually handled via multiple threads and the `async_trait` enforces that.

The fix is to indicate that only `Hasher`s that can be shared between threads are allowed. You can do this by using the `Sync` trait:

```
pub struct PGUserRepo {
    conn_pool: PgPool,
    hasher: &'static (dyn Hasher + Sync),
}
```

See [Understanding the Send trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428096/understanding-the-send-trait) to learn more about the difference between `Sync` and `Send` and their purpose.

Comment: `(dyn Hasher + Sync + Send)` allowed it to be used. Thanks!